# Replace a stray angle bracket within the document body

Tags: javascript, replace

I have several documents created in batch, and all of them contain a stray angle bracket `<` inside the document body which was accidentally added in the batch processing.

Using plain JavaScript, I want to replace the stray bracket with an empty string, but I am having a very hard time accomplishing it. This is what I have tried:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("</p><<p>", "</p><p>");
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Replace test</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Sentence 1....</p><<p>Sentence 2....</p> <!-- how to remove the stray bracket < between the two paragraphs? -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `.replace( new RegExp("</p><<p>", "g" ), ''</p><p>" )`?

Comment: Your approach looks like it should work. Didn't it? Or are you looking for a more general solution? Is there any regularity as to where the stray bracket appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems replacing `&lt;` does fix your issue, so it feels like that stray one gets converted to an HTML entity while you are not looking,
so maybe for safety replace both kinds:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("&lt;<", "<")
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( "<<", "<" );
```

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("&lt;<", "<")
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( "<<", "<" );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Replace test</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Sentence 1....</p><<p>Sentence 2....</p> <!-- how to remove the stray bracket? -->

</body>
</html>
```